# Form tag getting stripped in one page of website but not in other

Tags: jquery, forms, codeigniter

I am building a website in CodeIgniter and facing a strange problem of form tag getting stripped.

I am including a MailChimp newsletter subscription form in sidebar and the same sidebar is used in multiple pages. For example in the home page it is like this and it works fine here and number of other pages:

[image: Subscription form home page]

However, on in a specific page where the same form view is loaded it looks like this:

[image: Subscription form on Artist page]

Even though the same Sidebar view is loaded here, if you notice the inspected element, Form tag has been stripped only on this specific page. The only related difference in this page is a form at the top used for search. But haven't written any specific code that could result in this stripping.

I can provide more details but if someone can give me any hint what should I be looking for or what could be the reason, I could proceed further

Comment: Try to look at Page source (right click on a page/Network tab -> HTML-response), not in Developer's Tool, it'll provide more information for You for this question

Comment: The HTML response does have the form tag intact, so clearly it is getting stripped after getting rendered. As the form tag also shows in Page source, but not when I inspect it. Any other hints I should be looking for?

Comment: So there're problems in syntax (try to look at HTML attributes, maybe them brakes code. name="" with name `very "strange name"` or maybe Your form doesn't closed)